# DateTime::diff returns incorrect +1 hour difference

Tags: php, datetime

I have to DateTime objects:

```
object(DateTime)[561]
  public 'date' => string '1970-01-01 11:55:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Vilnius' (length=14)

object(DateTime)[563]
  public 'date' => string '2014-01-29 11:55:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Vilnius' (length=14)
```

and surprisingly DateTime::diff for these returns:

```
object(DateInterval)[565]
  public 'y' => int 44
  public 'm' => int 0
  public 'd' => int 28
  public 'h' => int 1
  public 'i' => int 0
  public 's' => int 0
  public 'weekday' => int 0
  public 'weekday_behavior' => int 0
  public 'first_last_day_of' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 16099
  public 'special_type' => int 0
  public 'special_amount' => int 0
  public 'have_weekday_relative' => int 0
  public 'have_special_relative' => int 0
```

Any ideas where that +1 hour differece could arise from?
Using PHP 5.4.25
Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Please, post your code so we could check

Comment: I have found this problem while digging deeper after running into problem using Zend\Form\Element\Date element with Zend\Validator\DateStep. Date input field has an option which sets the **minimum** step of date input which was set to **1 day**. Input is in format Y-m-d and is selected by JS calendar so it naturally has a step of 1 day. But the form does not validate, while DateStep validator detects 1 hour change between dates, while minimum step is 1 day. Furthermore, it seems to be working fine with WAMP using PHP 5.3.

Comment: In any case, for PHP 5.4+ [I couldn't reproduce](http://3v4l.org/mDiEU) that situation.

Comment: [The problem is reproducible](http://3v4l.org/uHpCB) by @MarcoS answer on php5.4+. The problem with your example is that  `setTimezone()` does not really modify the timestamp on an existing DateTime object. Anyway, it seems that PHP5.4+ behaviour is the correct one (as the timezone has changed in history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compared times are **local** and it seems there was a historic change in timezone for `Europe/Vilnius` from UTC+3h in 1970 to UTC+2h in 2014:

```
$ export TZ="Europe/Vilnius"
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> Time.mktime(1970,1,1)
=> Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 +0300 1970
irb(main):002:0> Time.mktime(2014,1,1)
=> Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 +0200 2014
```

The change seem to occur sometime back in 1990.

*language is ruby, but it uses the same OS backend for time functions and timezone data as php*

Comment: Thanks! That is the reason indeed. To be specific +02:00 timezone was introduced in 01/01/2003.

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy does not show, here, with php 5.3.3...:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 11 2013 03:29:57)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Vilnius");
    $datetime1 = new DateTime('1970-01-01 11:55:00');
    $datetime2 = new DateTime('2014-01-29 11:55:00');
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    print_r($interval);
?>
```

gives

```
    DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 44
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 28
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 16099
)
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in my reply to original post, it also seems to be working fine on machine with WAMP using PHP 5.3.

Comment: Sorry, I answered before than your comment... :-)

Comment: However, as showed (http://3v4l.org/mDiEU) by Alma Do, it doesn't occur neither with most recent PHP...